# How to change controls position and add a mouse out fade out effect in flash playback component

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, skinning, flvplayback

Hello i'm importing a video in flash cs5, using actionscript 3.0.
I have copy the SkinOverPlay.fla and i'm changing it to fit my needs.

I am looking for just a play/pause button (no other controls) in the center of the screen that disapear when the mouse it out of the video.

I am looking also on how to play the video in loop.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the playback controls, you can do this without using a skin by specifying the object to use for controls. For example:

```
flvPlayback.playButton = playbtn;
```

Here's a great article form adobe on customizing the FLVPlayback.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/custom_flvcomp.html

As for looping the video, you can do this by listening for the `VideoEvent.COMPLETE` event and then playing the video again. I'm pretty sure that this event isn't very consistent. So if you looking to loop a video animation and have it be seamless from end to begginning you might want to add a enter frame listener and check the playheadtime or use cue points.